# Connecting Remote Machine by using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to connect a remote computer by using RDP (mstsc.exe) from Excel (VBA macro). I am using the following code for this.

**Code:**

```
Sub Connect()    
    RDPWindow = Shell("C:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe /admin /v:" & "ServerName", 1)   
End Sub
```

but I don't want to enter my credentials manually. How can I add that thing in my code so that I can directly connect any remote machine by using specific credentials?

Answer (score 3):

Place the credentials in the credentials store keyed to the remote address/name by using `shell` to execute:

```
 cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/10.1.2.3 /user:UUUU /pass:XXXX
```

Run TS with:

```
 mstsc /v:10.1.2.3
```

To remove when you are done:

```
 cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/10.1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the username and password in not possbile, [because there is no parameter for this.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-line-parameters-remote-desktop-connection#1TC=windows-7)

But Mstsc supports [connection files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg156129%28v=winembedded.70%29.aspx)